# Finding the steady state solutions of a model.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, mathematical-modeling, mathematical-biology

**Problem:**

> Find the steady states and check for stability of the model
> \begin{align*}
>     X_{t+1} &= rX_te^{r(1-X/k)-aY_t} \\
>      Y_{t+1} &= X_t(1-e^{-aY_t}) \end{align*}

**Attempt:**
Calculating the steady states:
\begin{align*}
    X(1-re^{r(1-X/k)-aY})=0 &\rightarrow X=0 \\
    Y=X(1-e^{-aY}) &\rightarrow Y=0
\end{align*}
Thus $(0,0)$ is a trivial steady state. We also have
$$ X(1-re^{r(1-X/k)-aY})=0 \rightarrow \frac{1}{r}=e^{-(aY-r)} \rightarrow \log r = aY -r \rightarrow Y= \frac{\log r +r }{a}$$
and $$\frac{\log r +r }{a}= X \bigg( 1- \frac{1}{re^r}\bigg) \rightarrow X = \frac{re^r(\log r+r)}{a(re^r -1)}$$
Thus a non-trivial state is, with $r>1$
$$\bigg( \frac{re^r(\log r+r)}{a(re^r -1)},\frac{\log r +r }{a}\bigg).$$
Did I made a mistake here? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have with $X \ne 0$:
$$
X\left(1-re^{r(1-X/k)-aY}\right)=0 \implies \frac{1}{r}=e^{-(aY-r)}
$$
but shouldn't it be
$$
X\left(1-re^{r(1-X/k)-aY}\right)=0 \implies \frac{1}{r}=e^{-(aY-r+rX/k)}
$$

---

**UPDATE**
Assuming $X\ne 0$, the second equation yields
$$
X = \frac{Y}{1-e^{-aY}} = \frac{Ye^{aY}}{e^{aY}-1}
$$
and we can plug this into the first one. We get:
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{1}{r} &= e^{-(aY-r+rX/k)} \\
\ln r &= aY-r+\frac{r}{k} X \\
r + \ln r &= aY + \frac{r}{k} \frac{Ye^{aY}}{e^{aY}-1} \\
\end{split}
$$
which I believe is transcendental, so does not have an easily expressible analytic solution.

Comment: Thanks! I've already tried this before, from here I'm stuck computing for $X$ and $Y$. Can you enlighten me?

Comment: @TokitaOhma may not be an easy analytic solution, will try to think about it later today

Comment: If $X^*\neq 0$, then $Y^*=0$. You should be able to solve the last equation directly from here. @TokitaOhma

Comment: @Paichu how does that follow?